# Importing and parsing a large CSV file with go and app engine's datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, go, google-cloud-datastore

Locally I am successfully able to (in a task):

- Open the csv
- Scan through each line (using Scanner.Scan)
- Map the parsed CSV line to my desired struct
- Save the struct to datastore

I see that [blobstore has a reader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference#NewReader) that would allow me to[`read the value directly using a streaming file-like interface.`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/) -- but that seems to have a limit of 32MB. I also see there's a bulk upload tool -- bulk_uploader.py -- but it won't do all the data-massaging I require and I'd like to limit writes (and really cost) of this bulk insert.

How would one effectively read and parse a very large (500mb+) csv file without the benefit of reading from local storage?

Comment: Host it somewhere else and parse it over http, only thing I can think of really as I'm not that familiar with GAE.

Comment: @OneOfOne That won't work because I won't be able to parse the file in the time before GAE forces a timeout on the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to look at the following options and see if it works for you :

1. Looking at the large file size, you should consider using [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/) for the file. You can use the command line utilities that GCS provides to upload your file to your bucket. Once uploaded, you can look at using the JSON API directly to work with the file and import it into your datastore layer. Take a look at the following: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples
2. If this is like a one time import of a large file, another option could be spinning up a Google Compute VM, writing an App there to read from GCS and pass on the data via smaller chunks to a Service running in App Engine Go, that can then accept and persist the data.

Comment: 1. It does not look like the GAE runtime for go currently supports GCS yet. Or at least it's not documented. In the "storing data" section of the GAE documentation, there's only blob store and it says that `In addition to system wide safety quotas, a limit applies specifically to the use of the Blobstore: the maximum size of Blobstore data that can be read by the application with one API call is 32 megabytes.`. So I'm still stuck with a hard limited io stream. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/

Comment: 2. This might be workable -- but still a real pain. I'm still hopeful that's there another option available to me. Thanks for your response Romin.

Comment: I put in the wrong link to the Go GCS Sample and have corrected my response above - so please check if that works for you. You can use the JSON API directly. Additionally, I thought that your file is large but individual records are smaller and you want to process those and put that in the store. If the blobs itself are large, then you will need to keep that data individually in GCS itself and reference them from your GAE App.

Answer (score 1):

Not a the solution I hoped for, but I ended up splitting the large files into 32MB pieces, uploading each to blob storage, then parsing each in a task.

It aint' pretty. But it took less time than the other options.